# Find an element in a nested dictionary in MongoDB (python)

Tags: python, mongodb

I inserted the following structure in a MongoDb collection :

```
{
"_id": {
    "$oid": "5fb25b0f9d093cdeeb11649a"
},
"Kenya": {
    "b8": [{
        "bw": 2.5,
        "start_freq": 880,
        "stop_freq": 882.5,
        "operator": "Telkom Kenya"
    }, {
        "bw": 7.5,
        "start_freq": 882.5,
        "stop_freq": 890,
        "operator": "Yu Essar"
    }, {
        "bw": "10",
        "start_freq": 890,
        "stop_freq": 900,
        "operator": "Safaricom"
    }, {
        "bw": "5",
        "start_freq": 900,
        "stop_freq": 905,
        "operator": "Telkom Kenya"
    }, {
        "bw": "10",
        "start_freq": 905,
        "stop_freq": 915,
        "operator": "Airtel"
    }, {
        "bw": 2.5,
        "start_freq": 925,
        "stop_freq": 927.5,
        "operator": "Telkom Kenya"
    }, {
        "bw": 7.5,
        "start_freq": 927.5,
        "stop_freq": 935,
        "operator": "Yu Essar"
    }, {
        "bw": "10",
        "start_freq": 935,
        "stop_freq": 945,
        "operator": "Safaricom"
    }, {
        "bw": "5",
        "start_freq": 945,
        "stop_freq": 950,
        "operator": "Telkom Kenya"
    }, {
        "bw": "10",
        "start_freq": 950,
        "stop_freq": 960,
        "operator": "Airtel"
    }]
```

Using Python, I would like to retrieve for instance all the elements contained in b8, but using the find method I don't find the right query to achieve that... (I'm an absolute beginner in MongoDB).

I've tried :

```
pprint.pprint(client.collection.find_one("Kenya.b8"))
```

and other alternatives, but didn't get to the expected result.

Can someone indicate me the syntax for that ?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! It would be so much helpful if you can include in your question the queries you have tried so far

Answer (score 0):

Try with `client.collection.find_one({},{"Kenya.b8":1})`

Then, if you need to obtain the list of elements, just select the corresponding keys `client.collection.find_one({},{"Kenya.b8":1})['Kenya']['b8']`

Comment: Alright, thank you! I managed to use the country as the _id in MongoDB and then by  using `self.collection.find_one({"_id": "Kenya"})` I have been able to retrieve the list of elements as you described it.